# elliptic integral with singularities

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, na.numerical-analysis, mathematical-software, elliptic-integrals

I need to calculate elliptic integrals with singularities, up to a huge number of digits (250-1000).  The problem is that Wolfram Mathematica can't do so many digits, and Pari intnum doesn't handle singularities as it seems.

This is an example of what I have to integrate written in latex:

$$\int_4^{+\infty}\frac {dx} {2 \sqrt{x^3 - 112x + 400}}$$

What software and command should I use?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Wolfram Mathematica can't do so many digits". I can do 2500 digits in a blink of an eye. (you Integrate[f[x], {x, 4, Infinity}] first, then do N[%, 1000], or whatever)

Comment: Actually the elliptic curve routines in **gp** can do this
(in addition to the many other useful features like finding
the conductor, which here is the famous $5077$).
If you set the desired precision with **\p** and then say
**E = ellinit([0,0,0,-112,400])** then **E[15]** and **E[16]**
are the real and imaginary periods, and **ellztopoint([4,4])**
will give you the desired integral (or maybe twice that integral)
up to some period or half-period, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PARI/GP for high-precision evaluations of elliptic integrals, with boundary singularities, but it requires some preprocessing, as explained here:

Jörg Waldvogel, [Computing Integrals of Analytic Functions to High Precision](http://www.sam.math.ethz.ch/~joergw/Projects/integrals.pdf) (2008)

> We present a set of numerical quadrature algorithms which typically
>   show exponential convergence for analytic integrands, even in the
>   presence of integrable boundary singularities. The algorithms are
>   based on mapping the integration interval onto the entire real axis,
>   together with suitable transformations of the integrand, preferably to
>   a doubly-exponentially decaying function. The transformed integrals
>   are approximated efficiently by the trapezoidal rule; the approximation
>   error may be analyzed by means of Fourier theory. This method
>   results in a practicable algorithm for computing analytic integrals
>   to a precision of hundreds – or thousands – of digits. An almost fully automated
>   implementation in PARI/GP is given.

Comment: I read the explanation. But I don't get which command should I use in Pari and how? I used just intnum, and the result was not correct.

Comment: thanks for the help. I see the link to the article now. I will read the article, I hope I will get it.